# Javacript Procedure on Snowflake returns an empty JSON

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

i have been trying to use Javascript in a Snowflake worksheet for a simple procedure. The idea is to search for a particular word in a schema. The output of the following procedure only returns an empty JSON. Any idea where this is going wrong? Thanks in advance.
(Ultimately i would like to store the output in a temporary table and output it)

```
create or replace procedure search(schema_to_search varchar, search_term varchar)
  returns variant
  language javascript
  as
  $$
    var search_schema = schema_to_search ;
    var search_term = search_term ;
    var result_set1 = "" ;  
    var get_columns = "SELECT COLUMN2, COLUMN2 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =  '" + search_schema + "';" ;
    
    var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement({
       sqlText: get_columns
    });


    try
    {
    var result_set1 = statement1.execute();

    return result_set1;

    }
    catch(err){return "error "+err;}
    
   
    while(result_set1.next())
    {
        var db = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
       
        
    }

    return result_set1;
  $$
  ;
 
call search('schema_name', 'a_searc_term');
```

Output :

```
{
  "getColumnCount": {},
  "getColumnDescription": {},
  "getColumnName": {},
  "getColumnScale": {},
  "getColumnSqlType": {},
  "getColumnType": {},
  "getColumnValBoxedType": {},
  "getColumnValue": {},
  "getColumnValueAsString": {},
  "getNumRowsAffected": {},
  "getQueryId": {},
  "getRowCount": {},
  "getSqlcode": {},
  "isColumnArray": {},
  "isColumnBinary": {},
  "isColumnBoolean": {},
  "isColumnDate": {},
  "isColumnNullable": {},
  "isColumnNumber": {},
  "isColumnObject": {},
  "isColumnText": {},
  "isColumnTime": {},
  "isColumnTimestamp": {},
  "isColumnVariant": {},
  "isDml": {},
  "next": {},
  "setCResultSet": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a resultset. This is why you see the method names etc in JSON.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#object-resultset

If you want to return the rows in this resultset, you may open a loop, read each row, add the values into a variable and return it:

```
try
{
var result_set1 = statement1.execute();
var res = [];
  
  while(result_set1.next())
  {
      res.push( result_set1.getColumnValue(1) );


  }

}
catch(err){return "error "+err;}

   
return res;
```